# Overwrite object methods / functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the `original.js` file, but I want to change some things in it. I can't modify `original.js`, but I can add another `better.js` file so that I could overwrite some functions of `original.js`

`original.js` contains:

```
MyHandler = {
   data:{},
   var1:false;
   handlers:{},

   init:function(handlers){
       function1();
       function2();
   }
   function1:function()
   {
    // function1 code that needs to be replaced
   };
}

$(document).ready(function ()
{
///...some code
      MyHandler.init();
}
```

I want to rewrite `function1()` with new content.
What should I put within `better.js` file?

P.S. I know `better.js` **should follow after** `original.js`.

I've tried to put the code below to `better.js`, but it doesn't work (seems like none of `function1` work then)

```
MyHandler = {
   function1:function()
   {
    // new code
   };
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You'r problem does not seem to have anything to do with jQuery. There is no such thing as a "jQuery function".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do like this:

```
if (!MyHandler) { MyHandler = {};}
MyHandler.function1 = function() { ... };
```

Or you can use jQuery $.extend api method.

Comment: +1, this is how it can be done.  You should note that the new `function` will not be able to access the internal data (e.g. `MyHandler.data`).

Comment: @El: Depends on how the function is called and the actual setup. There is not enough information to make such a statement. It looks like the function could easily access `MyHandler.data` because `MyHandler` appears to be global. Or if the function is called with `MyHandler.function1()`, the property can be accessed with `this.data`.

Comment: You're quite right; I glanced too quickly and thought it was the revealing module pattern.